# GCC, constant tables and .rodata

Tags: c++, c, gcc, constants

I have a strange problem with gcc and constants and .rodata

Let's assume:

```
typedef const struct {
   const char *a;
} data_t;

typedef const struct {
  const data_t d[2];
} bulk_data_t;
```

Now if I have:

```
bulk_data_t bd[] = {
{{
 "Test1", "Test2"
}}
};
```

My struct goes to .rodata

However:

```
const char *test_const = "Test1";
const bulk_data_t bd[] = {
{{
 test_const, "Test2"
}}
};
```

My data will go to .data (problem is, it is not defined read only and the test_const is actually initialised by code).

It's compiled as C++ code because C standard does not allow defining char constants outside struct definition.

Any idea how to force gcc to make it into .rodata? Forcing it by adding **attribute**((section(".rodata"))) causes very strange outcomes at linker level.

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: *"It's compiled as C++ code because C standard does not allow defining char constants outside struct definition."* - huh? This is news to me.

Comment: If you compile as C++ anyway then use constexpr as lot you can.

Comment: Anyway `const char test* = "x";` does not make `test` a constant variable, it's just a pointer to constant memory, so I guess that's what GCC doesn't like. Try `const char test[] = "x";` or `const char *const test = "x";` instead.

Comment: The difference between C and C++ is that C doesn't regard `const` qualified variables as compile-time constants.

Comment: GCC does not compile this (tdm64 on Win10, GCC 10.3.0) and errors because of the non-`const` initializer.

Answer (score 1):

`const char *test_const = "Test1";` defines a non-constant pointer to constant characters and initializes it with the address of a string literal, an unnamed array of constant characters.

To get what you want, you need to add another `const` to make the pointer constant, too:

`const char * const test_const = "Test1";`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not do the work. Later I will try to figure out what happens when compiling with clang. It might be just gcc being unpleasant.

Comment: I tried it with GCC 10 for Win10 and checked the generated assembly. It works for me. You might want to edit your question and add(!) the [mre] that shows the issue.